# Editing camel routes on routeContext with Camel Fuse not working

Tags: eclipse, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I just installed Jboss Tools Integration Stack for Eclipse Mars to be able to edit Camel routes in a graphic way. Problem is that it only load routes that are defined inside

```
<camelContext id="context1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="planner1">
        ...
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

But in our project to increase modularity, we have grouped routes in several files using

```
<routeContext id="context2" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route autoStartup="true" id="planner2">
        ...
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

This same files can be displayed on Eclipse Luna with JBoss Fuse Tooling Apache Camel Editor version: 7.3.1.v20150810-1602-H64-Final.

**Is there a way to make it work on Eclipse Mars** with Jboss Fuse Tooling Apache Camel Editor version 8.0.0.Final-v20161003-0720-B128?

Comment: I doubt that will work with the graphical editor. From experience, if you want to have routes spread out it is better to go with the java dsl, although you can get it to work with the xml version as well. It is just easier with the java dsl.

Comment: Going from xml definition to Java dsl is not really an option at this point in the project. Meanwhile I keep doing it just by editing xmls as text files.

Comment: No Java DSL is not easier. Camel support both XML and Java as equal ways. Use what you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jorge,
the issue you encounter seems to be already reported. (see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-1996)

I expect that to be fixed with Fuse Tooling 9.1. As a workaround I can only suggest to stay with Camel Context for now.

Lars

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on it and I'll keep on working temporary changing to camelContext just for editing purposes.

Comment: Jorge, the issue is fixed in the upcoming version 10.2 which will be due in January 2018.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new release of the tooling that support Eclipse Mars.

Lars Heineman whom is a key developer on this tooling blogged recently about this: http://lhein.blogspot.se/2016/10/jboss-fuse-tooling-80-for-eclipse-mars.html